# How can I access the content of a hashtable with Solidity (Ethereum)?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have created a public hashtable, I wish to know how to access its content since it's public .

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this on a testnet or the public blockchain?

If it's not on a testnet, can you provide the address of the contract (which I assume contains the hashtable) so concrete examples can be provided?